# slider value to change the duration of spin using DoubleAnimation class

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, slider

I am trying to do a basic animation using the DoubleAnimation class in WPF. On a button click the rectangle spins. The cs code is

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.From = 0; // start from 0 to 360, full circle
da.To = 360;
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
rectangle1.RenderTransform = rt;
rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
```

What i am trying to do is to update the `da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))` value with the slider value.

Tried with slider value binding, but not able to get this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `Duration` is not enough. How fast the animation is controlled by the inner `AnimationClock`. This clock is initialized just once after you call `BeginAnimation()`. So you have to update the inner `AnimationClock` by using `ApplyAnimationClock()` method.

Also note that you should also set the `From` property to the currently animated value, so that when changing the Slider's Value, the `Angle` will be animated smoothly (without restarting from `0`):

```
//The ValueChanged handler for your Slider
private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, 
                                 RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
   da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(yourSlider.Value));
   da.From = rt.Angle;
   rt.ApplyAnimationClock(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da.CreateClock());
}
```

Note that I suppose the slider's Value corresponds to the number of ***milliseconds***, so the `Maximum` value of the Slider should be large enough (about several thousands) if you don't want your Rectangle to be rotated super fast. Also all the variables you declared should be able to access inside the `ValueChanged` handler.

One more important note is you should use `By` property here instead of `To`, like this:

```
da.By = 360;
```

That way you can just update the `From` without caring about the `To` (it is always 360 degrees rotated).